# Show that there exists a Householder matrix such that the $n-1$ Components of $Ha$ are null.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $H(v)=I -2\frac{vv^\top}{v^\top v}$ be Householder matrix where $v$ is a
vector non null.
Let $a=\{ a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}^T $  such that $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|>0$
Show that there exists a Householder matrix such that the $n-1$ Components of $Ha$ are null.

I know that there exists a vector such that $Hx=x$

Comment: Hi :) Try $v=\frac{1}{\|a-\lambda e\|}\cdot(a-\lambda e) $, where $\lambda=\|a\|$ and $e=(1, 0,0\cdots) $

Comment: @Jochen  I find that $Ha= \lambda e_1$ is it correct ? and why the condition $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|>0$ is required. what if  $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|=0$ ?

Comment: If $\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|=0$, then $a=\mathbf 0$ and it holds $Ha=a$ for all matrices $H$. There is no nonzero entry in $a$.

Comment: Sorry but why  is $Ha=a$ ?